# How run Docker with sync folder on Windows

Tags: windows, nginx, docker

Well using Kitematic on Windows and starting the container hello-world-nginx. I'm totally able to edit the file on Windows and see the modifications at the browser.

But when I create some image and try to edit the file (html), nothing happens.

Here's the command:

```
docker build -t a-example . && docker run --name a-example -i -t -v //c/Users/pablo/htdocs/www/a-example/src:/www -d -p 80:80 a-example
```

And here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/logs && touch /etc/nginx/logs/a-example.log

ADD ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD /src /www

VOLUME /www
```

Another question:

Is this message have something to do with?

> SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against
>   a non-Win dows Docker host. All files and directories added to build
>   context will have '-r wxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to
>   double check and reset permissions f or sensitive files and
>   directories.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use KiteMatic or Docker Machine to control my local docker instance.

However, Docker Machine uses a boot2docker iso (customized version of Tiny Core Linux with Docker) running in a VirtualBox vm. Virtual Box provides guest Additions to mount host machine folders.

Refer to [Boot2Docker guidelines at the time of Docker 1.9.1 release](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/cef800bee1810b57fdcaf5094fd12d1ae44b0a69/README.md#folder-sharing)

Or the [Docker Machine shares](https://github.com/docker/machine/commit/84a40bcc06b00ed846b212da2614105e9431a501):

```
On Windows: 
 - C:\Users mounted as /c/Users
On Linux:
 - /home mounted as /hosthome
On OSX:
 - /Users mounted as /Users
```

which is done through [Guest Additions](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/84a40bcc06b00ed846b212da2614105e9431a501/drivers/virtualbox/virtualbox.go#L368):

```
vbm("sharedfolder", "add", d.MachineName, "--name", shareName, "--hostpath", shareDir, "--automount")
```

If you opt to use samba shares from your windows host instead, you will need the appropriate TLC packages (from the FAQ):

#### How do I mount windows shares?

If the sharing computer is at least Windows 2000, you can mount the share with only the `filesystems-2.6.29.1-tinycore.tcz` extension.

In a root console:

```
mkdir /mnt/windows
mount -t cifs //9.53.216.11/myshare /mnt/windows -o user=myname,pass=mypassword
```

And after searching for `boot2docker` and `filesystems-2.6.29.1-tinycore.tcz` I got to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/641):

> `sudo find / -type d -name 'cifs'` seems to indicate that CIFS (Samba) client  in the right kernel version is already there... allowing us to run

```
sudo mount -t cifs //MYPC/hostgithub ~/windows -o user=USER
```

> on the boot2docker VM

#### Using Docker Volumes

It seems Docker Volumes are a new proposal for handling host folders for Developer Environments, see:

- [Docker-Volume-Netshare](https://github.com/gondor/docker-volume-netshare): Although this requires `nfs-common` or `nfs-utils` (depending on your distro) to be available on the docker machine, this may not work for CoreOS / Boot2Docker without some other tricks.

  It should actually work on boot2docker considering how Docker-Volume-Netshare [just wraps](https://github.com/gondor/docker-volume-netshare/blob/c0c1ce8ea48d8e8225c8ce22bb7ddaad2fde9180/netshare/drivers/cifs.go#L178) shell exec `/bin/sh -c "mount -t cifs ..."` command. If you use the [so0k/mount.cifs_copy](https://hub.docker.com/r/so0k/mount.cifs_copy/) on CoreOS you may need a way to specify the path to cifs `/opt/bin/mount.cifs`.
- For Windows users, note also [my blog post](http://docker-saigon.github.io/post/Swarm-Week-2016-Part1/) using the netshare volume driver mentioned above to provision mounts from the Windows host across a Swarm Cluster.

**Note**: Be careful when using `git-for-windows` and `git-bash` as I'm having issues with these converting the paths I pass on to docker.exe

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your volume is available so your container is displaying the static content from `/src` that you `ADD`ed during the image build.

Kitematic runs a VirtualBox linux machine which runs your docker containers.

The path you have used for the volume: `//c/Users/pablo/htdocs/www/a-example/src:/www` looks suspect as that's the full windows path.

Docker machine (which is what kitematic uses underneath to manage the virutal machine) will map `C:\Users` to `/Users` by default

Try `--volume /Users/pablo/htdocs/www/a-example/src:/www`

Comment: Here's what i got: "invalid value "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\Users\\pablo\\htdocs\\www\\a-example\\src;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\www" for flag -v"